# "if not exist" with "goto" isn't working (just skips) and "else" variant also not working (Windows batch file)

Tags: windows, batch

I'm trying to create commands in a batch file where, if a certain nVidia file exists, it will encode a video using the graphics card - but if that nVidia file isn't there, it skips to another label to use another command.

This doesn't skip to the `:SOFTWARE_ENCODE` label if nvcuda.dll does not exist at the location:

```
if exist "%SYSTEMDRIVE%\Windows\System32\nvcuda.dll" goto :NVIDIA_ENCODE
if not exist "%SYSTEMDRIVE%\Windows\System32\nvcuda.dll" goto :SOFTWARE_ENCODE
```

If nvcuda.dll does exist then the above works and it skips to the `:NVIDIA_ENCODE` label.

I Googled around and saw someone solve it by using `else` with parentheses but that also doesn't work:

```
if exist "%SYSTEMDRIVE%\Windows\System32\nvcuda.dll" (goto NVIDIA_ENCODE) else goto SOFTWARE_ENCODE
```

The same result happens, it seems to just skip the rest of the batch file if nvcuda.dll does not exist.

I know both nVidia encode and software encode work to encode the video because I have commented out the `if exist` and `if not exist` parts, testing each (ffmpeg) encode command individually.

(I'm renaming nvcuda.dll to ".bak" when testing the software encode).

I remember this happening in the past and have no idea why it ignores `goto` if used with `if not exist`.

Any solution is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT: Here's the whole batch file...**

```
if not DEFINED IS_MINIMIZED set IS_MINIMIZED=1 && start "" /min "%~dpnx0" %* && exit

:: ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:: This part swaps the first and last 4 characters around...
:: (This processes all files in sub-folders, but I want to make it only process files next to the batch file)...

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
echo.
for /f "delims= eol=:" %%f in ('dir /b /a-d G???????*.* ????G???*.*') do (
set filename=%%~nf
set firstfour=!filename:~0,4!
set secondfour=!filename:~4,4!
echo %%f ^> !secondfour!!firstfour!!filename:~8!%%~xf
ren %%f !secondfour!!firstfour!!filename:~8!%%~xf
)

set /a Index=1


:: ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:: This part renames the files 001, 002, 003 and so on.

for /r %%i in (*.mp4) do ( 
    rem if number is less than 10, append 9 to file name
    if !Index! lss 10 (
        rename "%%i" 00"!Index!.mp4"
    ) else (
        rename "%%i" "0!Index!.mp4"
    )
    
    set /a Index+=1
)


:: ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:: Delete junk files...
del "*.LRV"
del "*.THM"


:: ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
rem    Create TEMP folder for files to be created in... 
if not exist "TEMP" md "TEMP" 


:: ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:: Use nVidia to encode if that driver file is installed...
:: Not working, but will work if nvcuda.dll is there...
:: if exist %SYSTEMDRIVE%\Windows\System32\nvcuda.dll (goto NVIDIA_ENCODE) else goto SOFTWARE_ENCODE

:: Original lines also not working...
if exist "%SYSTEMDRIVE%\Windows\System32\nvcuda.dll" goto :NVIDIA_ENCODE
if not exist "%SYSTEMDRIVE%\Windows\System32\nvcuda.dll" goto :SOFTWARE_ENCODE


:: ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:: Convert to 1080p...

:NVIDIA_ENCODE

rem    Convert video files...
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /b *.mp4') DO start /wait /min ffmpeg.exe -y -i "%%G" -vcodec hevc_nvenc -vf scale=1920:-2,fps=23.976 -b:v 4000k -acodec aac -b:a 192k -ar 44100 -ac 2 "TEMP\%%~nG.mp4" -hide_banner

goto :JOIN_FILES


:SOFTWARE_ENCODE

rem    Convert video files...
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /b *.mp4') DO start /wait /min ffmpeg.exe -y -i "%%G" -vcodec libx265 -vf scale=1920:-2,fps=23.976 -b:v 4000k -acodec aac -b:a 192k -ar 44100 -ac 2 "TEMP\%%~nG.mp4" -hide_banner

goto :JOIN_FILES


:: ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:: Join the files into one video...
:JOIN_FILES
(for %%i in (TEMP\*.mp4) do @echo file '%%i') > mp4_file_list.txt
For %%a IN ("TEMP\*.mp4") DO Set "mp4file=%%~na"
start /wait /min ffmpeg.exe -y -f concat -safe 0 -i mp4_file_list.txt -c copy "%mp4file%_JOINED.mp4" -hide_banner
del mp4_file_list.txt


:: ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:: Delete the TEMP folder...
rd /s /q "TEMP\"


:: ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:: Rename the "*_JOINED.mp4" file with todays date and " - GoPro Video" at the end.
:: (The dating method follows the format: YYYY-MM-DD) [May not work on non-UK systems]
For /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%c-%%b-%%a)
ren "*_JOINED.mp4" "%mydate% - GoPro Video.mp4"

:: Create a folder "Converted Video" and move the newly converted video file to it.
if not exist "Converted Video" md "Converted Video"
MOVE /Y "%mydate% - GoPro Video.mp4" "Converted Video"


:: ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:: Rename any old files back to mp4 again that got moved/renamed at the start...
for /r %%x in (*.S6C8JHVH2E7L4BX9) do ren "%%x" *.mp4


:: ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:: Open folder with finished video...
explorer "Converted Video"


:: ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
exit
```

If I run this on its own with an MP4 in the folder then it does work:

```
:: ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:: Use nVidia to encode if that driver file is installed...

if exist "%SYSTEMDRIVE%\Windows\System32\nvcuda.dll" goto :NVIDIA_ENCODE
if not exist "%SYSTEMDRIVE%\Windows\System32\nvcuda.dll" goto :SOFTWARE_ENCODE


:: ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:: Convert to 1080p...

:NVIDIA_ENCODE
rem    Convert video files...
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /b *.mp4') DO start /wait /min ffmpeg.exe -y -i "%%G" -vcodec hevc_nvenc -vf scale=1920:-2,fps=23.976 -b:v 4000k -acodec aac -b:a 192k -ar 44100 -ac 2 "TEMP\%%~nG.mp4" -hide_banner
goto :JOIN_FILES


:SOFTWARE_ENCODE
rem    Convert video files...
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /b *.mp4') DO start /wait /min ffmpeg.exe -y -i "%%G" -vcodec libx265 -vf scale=1920:-2,fps=23.976 -b:v 4000k -acodec aac -b:a 192k -ar 44100 -ac 2 "TEMP\%%~nG.mp4" -hide_banner
goto :JOIN_FILES


:: ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:JOIN_FILES

exit
```

I have tried using `pause` but to no avail.

Comment: Since you've used quotes around the path, try using the full path rather than the system variable, %SYSTEMDRIVE% .

Comment: Works for me. Could you please show us a whole `.bat` file that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Using the full path with and without quotes doesn't work. I have `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` further up the batch file, might that be causing it? How can I post the full thing, just edit it into the main question?

Comment: Yes. Please  [edit] your question to share a code snippet.

Comment: The full thing is there. It's not caused by `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` because I disabled it just before the nVidia part and it still ignores the line  `if not exist`.

Comment: @harrymc You write  "Works for me. Could you please show us a whole .bat file that demonstrates the problem? " <-- better to ask him to show a whole batch file that doesn't work but not THE whole batch file that he is using. A simple version that also doesn't work.

Comment: @barlop: Not very complicated: `if not exist "%SYSTEMDRIVE%\Windows\System32\nvcudaXXX.dll" echo not exists`.

Comment: anyhow, I now actually see you wrote "Could you please show us a whole .bat file that demonstrates the problem?"     I agree with that.. "a whole .bat file"  especially as his snippet didn't work. He shouldn't have included "the whole bat file" though

Comment: On it's own (using echo with a pause) it does work for me too, just not in the full batch file. The full thing is edited into the question now ;)

Comment: @bat_cmd can you make  the bat file as simple as possible while still demonstrating the problem,   thats what you should be doing anyway to troubleshoot it and if you did that you might even end up solving it yourself!

Comment: also have you tried pause statements and echo statements in your bat file to help you trace it? this will also help you compose simple versions of the problem.. eventually it gets far more solvable with that kind of troubleshooting method

Comment: @bat_cmd: Just a small note - your first `if exist` line is not required, since `:NVIDIA_ENCODE` follows these two IF statements. Even so, the code should work. I second the idea of adding debug statements to debug the script.

Comment: This is happening because the bat file is being run from an AutoIt3 exe. Every other thing the batch file does is working, except this one thing `if not exist`. It's not about permissions or needing to run as an Administrator checking the file in system32 because `if exist` does work. I am past caring to be honest, I only wanted this to work in case I ever swapped out my nVidia card and it works for that so, I give up, it's just too absurd to even try to fix.

Comment: @bat_cmd  when you say if exist works, do you mean when tested outside of autoit. Maybe autoit has an issue with the environment variables. What if you change ` "%SYSTEMDRIVE%\Windows\System32\nvcuda.dll` to an absolute path e.g.  assuming your system drive is C, "C:\Windows\System32\nvcuda.dll`

Comment: I worked it out in the end, the AutoIt3 script must be compiled as a 64-Bit executable, for it to run the batch file and the batch file work properly. Why this only applies to that one line `if not exist "%SYSTEMDRIVE%\Windows\System32\nvcuda.dll" goto :SOFTWARE_ENCODE` or rather, the failure to go to that label (when it goes to all other labels perfectly fine) is just insane. Anyway, bizarrely, it's fixed, by making sure the compiled AutoIt3 exe is 64-Bit. @barlop the AutoIt script simply runs the batch file by name, there's no CMD stuff in the AutoIt3 script itself. Cheers.

Comment: well, number 1 step with troubleshooting would have clearly been for you to try it outside of autoit, since when troubleshooting you are supposed to be getting down to nuts and bolts! (though you didn't mention autoit since you didn't realise it was relevant), but had you done troubleshooting / normal troubleshooting, you might have seen straight away

Comment: I was running the entire thing each time (copying videos from the camera) and forgot I could break it up by leaving a video there and running the batch file. I am my own worst enemy. Sorry if this wasted your time. The question (had I known it was down to AutoIt3) shouldn't have been asked here.

Comment: no prob, it happens, it's still useful.. makes for an interesting question of why it fails within  autoit when autoit isn't compiling the bat file to 64bit, so i suppose if 32bit, and that question could be asked with the autoit tag.